# How can I modify item details in Odoo's Shop product view?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, odoo

I would like to add the internal reference number to the item description in the product listing of our Odoo shop. I'm able to add the internal reference number above the product thumbnail, but not within the description of the item. Here is a snippet of code from the website's XML:

```
<td t-att-colspan="td_product['x'] != 1 and td_product['x']" t-att-rowspan="td_product['y'] != 1 and td_product['y']" t-attf-class="oe_product" t-att-data-ribbon-id="td_product['ribbon'].id">
    <div style="float:left">Internal Ref. Number&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</div>
    <b t-field="product.default_code"/>
    <div t-attf-class="o_wsale_product_grid_wrapper o_wsale_product_grid_wrapper_#{td_product['x']}_#{td_product['y']}">
        <t t-call="website_sale.products_item">
            <t t-set="product_image_big" t-value="td_product['x'] + td_product['y'] &gt; 2"/>
        </t>
    </div>
</td>
```

I want to add   t-field="product.default_code" to below the item name as pictured below:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to extend the QWeb template `website_sale.products_item`?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the `website_sale.product_item` as below, This will add toggle button also in customize so you can enable and disable it.

```
 <template id="products_item_internal_reference" inherit_id="website_sale.products_item" active="True"
              customize_show="True" name="Product Internal Reference">
        <xpath expr="//*[hasclass('product_price')]" position="before">
            <h6 class="o_wsale_products_item_title mb-1">
                <a class="text-primary text-decoration-none" itemprop="default_code" t-att-href="product_href"
                   t-att-content="product.default_code" t-field="product.default_code"/>
            </h6>
        </xpath>
    </template>
```